# Properties of preferential attachment such as spectral gap

Tags: pr.probability, graph-theory, network-theory

**Short question:**
Is there a good math reference on the properties of preferential attachment graphs? In particular,  expansion properties seem to interest me.

**More details:**
I try to investigate the size of the smallest contagious set in preferential attachment graphs. A non-empty set of vertices in an undirected graph is called *cohesive* if any vertex in that set has at least half of its neighbors in that set. A set of vertices is called *contagious* if it intersects any cohesive set. What is the size of the smallest contagious set $h(G)$ in a preferential attachment graph $G$? In the [Barabsi-Albert model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barab%C3%A1si%E2%80%93Albert_model) with $n$ vertices each attached to $m$ previous vertices (average degree $2m$), it is not hard to show that  $h(G)/n$ is bounded away from $0$, for any fixed $m$. But, is this also the case for growing values of $m$?

Comment: I am not sure that you will find any useful answer to your question, but you might be interested in going through this paper by Farkas et al. "Spectra of “real-world” graphs: Beyond the semicircle law".